# Discord.py rewrite Voice channel question

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have seen many multiple sites for this but cant figure out the syntax for the program to get all the users id when connected to a specific voice channel. Ex: when a person joins a voice channel add "vcboi" role n when disconnected remove the role. pls no cogs and also all in ids no name ,I'm fine with ids

code:

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "|")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'bots up')
    print(bot)
    bot.loop.create_task(status())
#@bot.command()
async def status():
    role_id=831148974789623859
    role = discord.guild.get_role(role_id)
    while True:
        voice_channel = bot.get_channel(798812392677965824)
        member_ids = voice_channel.voice_states.keys()
        memids = []
        for member in member_ids:
            member. add_role(role)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
        
bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. Nobody is going to code all of this for you. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh I knew it i forgot to add code so sorry ill post it in 5 mins

Comment: i want the role to be added looks like i cant use ctx or message to get the role so pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use a different `event` for that and reform the check in order to use the code for more events/roles.

You can use the [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.on_voice_state_update) function in order to check in which channel the member is and based on that add or remove a role.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = before.channel or after.channel

    if channel.id == ChannelID: # Pass your channel ID
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: # Member joins the defined channel
            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=RoleID) # Inser RoleID
            await member.add_roles(role) # Role is given
        elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
            role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=RoleID)
            await member.remove_roles(role) # Role removed because he left the channel
```

***What is the code doing?***

`before.channel is None` = Checks that the user is/was not in a channel.

`after.channel is not None` = Checks the channel which the user joined and then adds the role to the user.

`before.channel is not None and after.channel is None` = User is not in a voice channel anymore.